# Transpose Columns into 1 Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8sry.png)

I have question about transposing (melting or stacking?) and joining data sets.

I have 3 dataframes (above) and I want to transform and join them to make the outcome that I have on the right.

I've been reading about stack, melt, transpose, and merge and am a bit confused.

Advice on getting the desired outcome?

Thanks!

Comment: It's better to attach your dataframes as code which we could use to help you. With picture it's more complex..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Country')

         2012  2013  2014
Country                  
AFG         1     4     7
AGO         2     5     8
ALF         3     6     9

df2 = df1.mul(2)
df3 = df1.mul(3)
```

You can `.stack()` and `pd.concat()`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.stack(), df2.stack(), df3.stack()], axis=1)
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'Year'})


  Country  Year  A   B   C
0     AFG  2012  1   2   3
1     AFG  2013  4   8  12
2     AFG  2014  7  14  21
3     AGO  2012  2   4   6
4     AGO  2013  5  10  15
5     AGO  2014  8  16  24
6     ALF  2012  3   6   9
7     ALF  2013  6  12  18
8     ALF  2014  9  18  27
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Stefan!

Unfortunately, this didn't produce the outcome I was looking for.

Instead, my result truncated out the Country column. Any thoughts on why this happened? Thanks for your help, btw - n00b with working with Dataframes in Pandas :-)

Comment: See updated. Need to `.set_index()` first if `Country` not in `index` for `.stack()` to work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, @Stefan!! 

Can you please also add back in the code you used for `.stack()` and `pd.concat()?`

Comment: Just let me know if you need anything else.